# Finding a Clifford algebra basis for a parallelization of a manifold "living in" larger space ex: $\mathbb{S}^{1}\subset\mathbb{R}^{2}$

Tags: differential-geometry, clifford-algebras

I'm looking at manifolds $M$ which are parallelizable (and orientable) having dimension n. Suppose this manifold “lives in” $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ Euclidean space. A good example of this would be the topological three-sphere: $$\mathbb{S}^{3}\subset\mathbb{R}^{4}$$

Now I'm interested in writing a global orthonormal basis in terms of Clifford algebras. For a local trivialization it is clear that a local Clifford basis is $Cl(3)$. However; for the global trivialization, this is insufficient, as there is more structure here.

For the general case, I'm guessing that a global trivialization of M is going to have to have it's Clifford basis written in terms of $Cl(n+1)$, which in the example would be $Cl(4)$. I expect that a global Clifford basis on M is then written as a linear combination of elements of $Cl(n+1)$.

Another example would be $\mathbb{S}^{1}\subset\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Can anyone please explain if this is correct, and how exactly one goes about doing this (the three-sphere example would be great!)???

For the interested reader, I'm interested in manifolds of signature 3,1 (Lorentzian manifolds) which are embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{4,2}$, One example of which is a space having a topology $\mathbb{S}^{3}\times\mathbb{S}^{1}$. Ultimately, I'm looking at the decomposition of the Clifford algebra therein into spinor spaces.

Comment: A global orthonormal basis of what? The tangent bundle? What do you mean by "orthonormal" without having picked a Riemannian metric?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan   Yes of the tangent bundle. Choose any Riemannian metric and go from there, I really don't care what metric is chosen, and of course a global orthonormal basis here will be non-holonomic/coordinate.  Thank you again, I was just trying to keep it as general as possible since the clifford algebra can be written independent of basis.

Comment: Please write \subset, not \in, for set inclusions.

Comment: @TedShifrin   Done, and thank you, my background is physics which often abuses your more precise notations.